# Typescript: Assigning a local variable name to an imported nested namespace

Tags: javascript, typescript, nativescript

I'm declaring a JAVA library in a separate file to build out the various classes and namespaces used within it so when I reference this from other files that utilize the JAVA library there will be associated comments and typings. *(This is for a NativeScript plugin btw which is why I'm mixing JAVA and JS).*

**javalib.ts**

```
export declare namespace org {
  export namespace fizz {
    export namespace buzz {
      export namespace libA {
        export class libAClassA { }
        export class libAClassB { }
      }

      export namespace libB {
        export class libBClassA { }
        export class libBClassB { }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It looks wild, and I could probably shorten it to just `export declare namespace org.fizz.buzz { ... }` but I'm outling it for now.

In another file that will be utilizing some of these classes *(i.e., libAClassA or libBClassB)* I'd like to of course import these namespaces to have the typings and references follow. I've so far been able to get it working like so:

**app.ts**

```
import * as pkg from './javalib';

let aliceClass = new pkg.org.fizz.buzz.libA.libAClassA();
let bobClass = new pkg.org.fizz.buzz.libA.libBClassB();
```

While this works, it's not ideal as having to write out the entirety of the namespace to reference this definition can become quite bothersome all for the added benefit of code visability while developing. I could instead just do a blanket `declare var org: any` and be done with it, but in an effort to better my future dev on this project as well as others I'd like to utilize this and set this up.

Is there any way to cast this namespace reference to a local var, similar to how in JAVA you can just do `import org.fizz.buzz;` and suddenly have references and access to everything within that namespace?

**ideal-app.ts**

```
let libA = org.fizz.buzz.libA;
let libB = org.fizz.buzz.libB; 

let aliceClass = new libA.libAClassA();
let bobClass = new libB.libBClassB();
```

Comment: Have you tried import * as pkg from './javalib/org/fizz/buzz/libA'; and then let aliceClass = new pkg.libAClassA();

Comment: That comes back with `Cannot find module './javalib/org/fizz/buzz/libA` likely because with Typescript / requiring files it doesn't create a virtual folder for nested namespaces.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20990

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do as you have in the **ideal-app.ts** but to make sure it's compatible with Webpack and Snapshot builds, initialise them inside a function call. Something like this,

```
let libA, libB;

function initializePackages() {
   if (!libA) {
     libA = org.fizz.buzz.libA;
     libB = org.fizz.buzz.libB; 
   }
} 

// Call it before accessing the variables
initializePackages();
let aliceClass = new libA.libAClassA();
let bobClass = new libB.libBClassB();
```

Comment: Neat idea, unfortunately this comes back as `Cannot find namespace libA` likely because it see's the `.` separator as a namespace? Oddly enough though, I've seen a reference online where you can cast something like `let javaPkg = java.lang;` so I thought I could do something similar with an imported file.

Comment: It should work, it does for me and you might be able to find similar code in most plugins and tns-core-modules. Is it a runtime exception or TypeScript one?

Comment: It works if I only wanted to reference the literal `JAVA` library. I would also have to add this to the file: `declare var org: any` and then I would be able to cast it to a variable. This would remove any ability for code hinting and type checking however, whereas I'm looking to still support that through the use of a definition or namespace file.

Comment: These stuffs also depend on your TypeScript configurations, if you apply type to the variable then it should work. It does on my end, so if you can can setup a playground / repo I can take a look for you.